# C# returning enumerator from generic recursive data structure using extension methods

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, ienumerable, ienumerator

I am trying to create an interface so that I can make a class recursive tree node data structure. That way, I can write generic extension methods which will deal with the generic tree traversal logic for anything which implements that interface without having to implement it in each concrete node class.

As part of this, I want to be able to make the tree node implement `IEnumerable<T>`, since you can iterate through the various nodes of the tree. However, I'm having issues implementing `GetEnumerator()` as a generic extension method due to issues with subclass types and casting.

```
public interface ITreeNode<out T>
    where T : ITreeNode<T>, IEnumerable<ITreeNode<T>>
{
    T Parent { get; }
    IEnumerable<T> Children { get; }
}

public static class TreeExensions
{
    public static T GetRoot<T>(this T node) where T : ITreeNode<T>, IEnumerable<ITreeNode<T>>
    {
        var currentNode = node;

        while (currentNode.Parent != null)
        {
            currentNode = currentNode.Parent;
        }

        return currentNode;
    }

    // IsRoot(), IsLeaf(), GetDepth(), etc.

    public static IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator<T>(this T node) where T : ITreeNode<T>, IEnumerable<ITreeNode<T>>
    {
        yield return node;
        foreach (var child in node.Children)
        {
            foreach(var descendant in child)
            {
                // Cannot implicity convert ITreeNode<T> to T
                yield return descendant;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Customer : Entity, ITreeNode<Customer>
{
    public Customer Parent { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Children { get; private set; }
}
```

In the example above, I'd like `GetEnumerator()` for a `Customer` object to return `IEnumerator<Customer>()`. However, the compiler will error because it can't `ITreeNode<Customer>` into `Customer`, even though `Customer` is a recursive data structure.

I've tried doing iterative and recursive versions, but I can't seem to get around this issue. Is this possible, or am I trying to do something you can't do?

Comment: Why is `GetEnumerator` not returning an `IEnumerator<TreeNode<T>>`?

Comment: Do you mean `public interface ITreeNode<out T> : IEnumerable<ITreeNode<T>> where T : ITreeNode<T>`? Why constrain `T` to implement `IEnumerable` as well?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay The reason why `GetEnumerator` returning `T`, not  `IEnumerator<ITreeNode<T>>` is because, in the example above, I'd want to iterate over the actual `Customer` object. If I return `IEnumerator<ITreeNode<Customer>>`, all I'd be able to do with that object is access the `Parent` and `Children` properties, which isn't very useful. What if I wanted to do something with the customer's name or ID?

Comment: @Sweeper I tried to also implement `IEnumerable<T>` because a tree is a recursive structure. Therefore, I could return an enumerator to iterate over the the subtree of a given node, which would allow me to write `foreach` loops such as `foreach(var childNode in node)`.

In the example above, if I had the root node, I could traverse over every customer object in the tree. It would effectively flatten the tree into an `IEnumerable`, since there might be instances where I want to use the `IEnumerable<T>`  extension methods.

Comment: One simple way would be to add a `T Self { get; }` property to your interface, then implement in `Customer` with `public Customer Self => this;`. That way you could `yield return descendant.Self;`.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I'd been reluctant to do that it seems a bit odd. It feels like it's breaking the semantics of a tree node interface to return a this pointer. At any rate, I've just made a generic `TreeNode<T>` class which contains `T Data`. I'm also no longer implementing `IEnumerable<T>` because it's making assumptions about the direction of enumeration. Instead, I'm implementing `GetAncestors()` and `GetDescendants()`. So I no longer have this issue.